# strange weird address in transaction after send bitcoin bitcoin-qt

Tags: transactions, bitcoin-core, security, sending, address-generation

as an example, I have the wallet with **address-A** (with 10 BTC)

If I send 1 BTC to someone (**address-B**) then in transaction I see

> **address-A** > 1 BTC > **address-B**
>
> **address-A** > 1 BTC > **address-C**

after, on **address-A** I have 8 BTC, but my *bitcoin-qt* show me 9 BTC (as it must be)

why it makes sends to strange **address-C** ?

=================

Found an answer here https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Change

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you send money to another address, the client selects one or more unspent outputs to get a sufficient amount to cover the amount you are sending.  Any excess is returned to your wallet using a change address.

In your case, it looks like you had an unspent output of 2 BTC.  Since a transaction completely consumes its inputs,  the transaction needs to send 1 BTC to your specified address and 1 BTC back to your wallet to account for the 2 BTC that were consumed.

Changes addresses are typically not displayed by the client.  If you are running Bitcoin-Qt, you can check all of the addresses in your wallet by entering the command

> listaddressgroupings

in the debug console.